# Why does Visual Studio 2013 recognize CSS3 display: flexbox, but not flex?

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013

On my CSS pages Visual Studio doesn't recognize flex, claiming it's not valid:

```
div {
    display: flex;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

It does however recognize flexbox :

```
div {
    display: flexbox;
    display: inline-flexbox;
}
```

Flexbox does not seem to be supported in any of the main browsers, yet flex is. Can anyone explain this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

VS2013 needs to have [Update 5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48129) installed and that will fix the CSS validation issue.

Answer (score 9):

`flex` and `inline-flex` *were*, at one point in time, [`flexbox` and `inline-flexbox` respectively](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120322/#display-flexbox). The new values represent an entirely new definition of the Flexbox module, and browser implementations have moved on with these new values.

Either the old values were current at the time VS2013 was released, or if not, then VS2013 shipped with an out-of-date CSS validator.

Note that the [W3C Jigsaw CSS validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator) has been updated to recognize the new values and consider the old values invalid.

Comment: @BoltClock: So is there a way to update VS2013's validator, or is that baked into the release?

Comment: @Superstringcheese: Not that I'm aware of, unfortunately. I'm sure a lot of people would like to know that as well.

Comment: If you update VS2013 to Update 5--maybe other updates work as well--it'll work for you.

Comment: @Sawtaytoes: Sweet, thanks. I see a [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11039029) was made earlier today along the same lines.

Comment: @BoltClock Looks like she wrote an answer as well which I up-voted.