# 2 images in row responsive

Tags: html, image, css, css-float

I want to make 2 images in the center of the page in a row.
My images have different size but I want them to be in the center and in the same line.
First I tried to use with row and col-50 in framework 7

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-50"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="col-50"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

But it doesn't work correctly then I did it manually with css styles this way

```
<div style="width:100%;display:inline-block;">
    <div style="width:50%;float:left">
        <img src="1.jpg" style="margin:auto;display:block" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left">
        <img src="2.jpg" style="margin:0 auto;display:block;"/>
        <span style="font-size: 40px; color: #4c4c4c; font-family: Calibri;">Logo company</span>
        <br />
        <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #4c4c4c; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;">write here your brand</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use flexbox, something like this

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: #f6f6f6">

<div dir="ltr" class="page-content center" style="min-width: 400px; min-height: 400px; margin: auto; width: 58%; padding: 20px;">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <!--<p style="text-align: center;">-->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-50">
             <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2ni7hjk.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-50">
                <img src="http://i68.tinypic.com/dunp0.png"/>
                <span style="font-size: 40px; color: #4c4c4c; font-family: Calibri;">logoeri</span>
                <br />
                <span style="font-size: 12px; color: #4c4c4c; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;">logo company is here</span>
            </div>
         </div>

    <!-- Header -->

    <div id="Header" style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; text-align: center; font-size: 30px; padding: 20px; color: white; background-color: #3eb780">
    the header is here
    </div>


    <!-- Center Container -->

    <div style="font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; background: white;padding: 20px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; direction: ltr; text-align: left;">           <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).


    </p>





        <!-- Footer -->
        <div style="text-align: center; color: #a2a2a2">
            <div style="width: 90%; margin: auto; padding: 20px;">
                Do not reply<br />


            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: that's weird, because I can see it correctly @AdirZoari

Comment: look on my post again , i edited it and post the snipcode

Comment: I changed the code, is this what you are looking for? @AdirZoari
this line is extra         <div class="content-block">

Comment: if you are using visual studio, check this stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124198/why-does-visual-studio-2013-recognize-css3-display-flexbox-but-not-flex @AdirZoari

Comment: do you know another way instead to update the visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code and also check snippet how's this working. I hope it is helpfull for you.

```html
<style>
.row img {
   display:inline-block;
}
.row{
  text-align:center;
}
</style>

<div class="row">
<img src="1.jpg">
<img src="2.jpg">
</div>
```

Thanks,

Comment: thanks for you time, but it's not works. don't forget in the second photo (the left photo) i have text behind the photo so i need to put it into div.

Answer (score 1):

Using display flex and a relative container inside the row you will be able to add text inside the image.

```css
.row{
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.col-50{
  width: 48.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
img{max-width: 100%;}

.rel{position:relative;}
.rel p{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0;}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-50">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></div>
  <div class="col-50">
    <div class="rel">
     <img src="https://placehold.it/200x300">
      <p>TEXT INSIDE THE IMAGE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rpqLfef3/)